# Visual Studio Enterprise RC 2015: Windows 10.0.10069 SDK etc install errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

**Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293 (0x80070643)**

**Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293  (0x80070643)**

**Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293  (0x80070643)**

Installing Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RC on Windows 10 Build 10130.  I dont know if its related but I had Windows SDK 10.0.10056 on the machine previously and Visual Studio 2013 and I first installed VS Community 2015.  All have been uninstalled since and these errors are on an install attempt after all of those were removed (I got the same errors whilst they were on there).

From the install log:

```
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:22:38]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin for secondary installer
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:22:38]i000: MUX:  Checking to see if the secondary installer pipe should be created
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:22:38]i000: MUX:  Creating secondary installer pipe: {386a44b6-1b61-419b-9d49-f8a37722dc01}
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:22:38]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: VSSecondaryInstaller_box
[0BC8:0FF0][2015-06-13T12:22:38]i000: MUX:  Begin connecting secondary installer pipe
[11E0:16FC][2015-06-13T12:22:38]i301: Applying execute package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5FE48C2F034F5E6FA0D78333EBDF5D53C17A180A\packages\SecondaryInstaller\SecondaryInstaller.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5FE48C2F034F5E6FA0D78333EBDF5D53C17A180A\packages\SecondaryInstaller\SecondaryInstaller.exe" /q /BurnBundleProviderKey {f0b67533-bfb8-4d6e-9e09-50ff776dbfca} /lcid 1033 /BaseDirectory "C:\Install" /xml "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\-1306121212.xml" /FeedUri "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=500682&clcid=0x409" /primarylog "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_enterprise_20150613115210.log" /skuSpecificHKLMHive Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 /launchaction Install  /installitems Win10SDK_Hidden;Win10_Emulator;Win10_VSTools;GitHubVS;Chrome;Git /Pipe {386a44b6-1b61-419b-9d49-f8a37722dc01} {b87c4132-5a5c-4174-b9ad-c5574eac6d50} -burn.ancestors={f0b67533-bfb8-4d6e-9e09-50ff776dbfca}'
[0BC8:0FF0][2015-06-13T12:22:39]i000: MUX:  Finished connecting secondary installer pipe
[0BC8:0CC0][2015-06-13T12:22:43]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10069
[0BC8:0CC0][2015-06-13T12:24:14]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.10069
[0BC8:0CC0][2015-06-13T12:24:31]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Tools for Windows 10 Universal Apps (Windows SDK 10.0.10069)
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:27:41]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:27:41]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:27:41]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293
[11E0:16FC][2015-06-13T12:28:15]e000: Error 0x80048646: Process returned error: 0x80048646
[11E0:16FC][2015-06-13T12:28:15]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1845325824  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 1668124672
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageComplete for secondary installer
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i000: MUX:  Disconnecting secondary installer pipe
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80048646 Msi Messages:Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147187130 (0x80048646), Error Message=Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293, Result Detail=, Vital=False, Package Action=Install, Package Id=VSSecondaryInstaller_box
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]w350: Applied non-vital package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box, encountered error: 0x80048646. Continuing...
[11E0:16FC][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {95160002-1163-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}, version: 16.0.3104.1200, package: SharePointClientComponents_v16_x64
[11E0:16FC][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i325: Registering dependency: {f0b67533-bfb8-4d6e-9e09-50ff776dbfca} on package provider: {95160002-1163-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}, package: SharePointClientComponents_v16_x64
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: IntelliTrace_x86
[11E0:16FC][2015-06-13T12:28:15]i301: Applying execute package: IntelliTrace_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3E58EC32-ED48-4808-96A0-27040861E587}v14.0.22823\packages\IntelliTraceCore\x86\intelliTrace_net.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1"'
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:17]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: IntelliTrace_x86 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 6504448  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 5832704
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:17]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:RollbackCleanup Restart:None
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:17]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[0BC8:0C90][2015-06-13T12:28:17]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01eb5124-513f-41ec-be78-8441a395bba9/0x80048646-windows-10-sdk-on-vs-2015-rc-cant-install?forum=vssetup